# Get input field inner html based of position of onclick event react tables

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I and trying to get the inner html value of the input field based from where the button is clicked input field shown below.

```
<input id="newanswer" placeholder="Create New Answer Here"></input>
```

I want to be able to get that value and add it as an argument the function below

```
<button
    className="ui negative basic button"
    onClick={() => onClick(questionid\\I want the input innerhtml here\\)}
  >Create New Answer</button>
```

[image: Table Here]

```
The component that renders the table below.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { currentloginid } from '../login/loginid.js';
import { deletequestion } from '../question/deletequestion.js';
import { createanswer } from '../answer/createanswer.js';
import {deleteanswer } from '../answer/deleteanswer.js';

export const ViewQuestionComponent = () => {
  let [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const handleViewQuestion = async () => {
    try {      
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost/gotaquestion/api/api.php?action=viewquestion', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      const result = await data;
      setState(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ViewQuestion onClick={handleViewQuestion} />
      <div id="questions">
        <Table rows={state}>
          <DeleteButton onClick={deletequestion} />
          <CreateNewAnswerButton onClick={createanswer} />
          <DeleteAnswerButton onClick={deleteanswer} />
        </Table>
      </div>
   </div>
  );
};

export function ViewQuestion({onClick}) {
    return (
        <Button onClick={onClick}>View Question</Button>
    );
}

export default ViewQuestion;

const Table = ({ rows, setIdTobeDeleted, children }) => (
  <table className="ui single line table">
    <tbody>
      {rows.map((row) => (
        <tr key={row.questionid}>
          <td>{row.question}</td>
          <td>{row.timestamp}</td>
          <td>{row.catagories}</td>
          <td>{row.answer === null ? "Not Answered" : row.answer}</td>
          <td>
            {React.cloneElement(children[0], { questionid: row.questionid })}
          </td>
          <td>
            {React.cloneElement(children[1], { questionid: row.questionid })}
          </td>
          <td>
            {React.cloneElement(children[2], { questionid: row.questionid })}
          </td>
          <td>{row.questionid}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);

const CreateNewAnswerButton = ({ questionid, onClick }) => (
  <>
  <input id="newanswer" placeholder="Create New Answer Here"></input>
  <button
    className="ui negative basic button"
    onClick={() => onClick(questionid)}
  >Create New Answer</button>
  </>
);

const DeleteButton = ({ questionid, onClick }) => (
  <button
    className="ui negative basic button"
    onClick={() => onClick(questionid)}
  >Delete Question</button>
);

const DeleteAnswerButton = ({ questionid, onClick }) => (
  <button
    className="ui negative basic button"
    onClick={() => onClick(questionid)}
  >Delete Answer</button>
);
```

Comment: There is only one input in your code ?

Comment: you can put `state` in each of your custom buttons like `CreateNewAnswerButton` . `const [value, setValue] = useState()`. `<input id="newanswer" value={value} placeholder="Create New Answer Here"></input>`

Comment: thes same question as @Lyes. bit confused about the code. if you have the buttons each row is it ok to set the same `id` property in each row?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, next to every create new answer button as seen in the image above, there is an input field, I want it so when a new answer button is clicked the will take the inner html of the input field to the left of it @Jerry